# how to apply stylesheet to wp frontend, via plugin i created?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin that when activated, will apply a stylesheet (located in the plugin folder) to the website that it is activated on, but i'm stuck. Below is how far i have gotten. I think i only have the code to load the stylesheet for the plugin itself? But i want to activate my plugin and apply a stylesheet to the frontend site. Any or all help would be appreciated.

*p.s. - i know there are other ways to load styles on the front end... like via your themes custom css section... but for what im working on i need this to be loaded through a plugin i am creating.*

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: plugin name
 * Plugin URI: http://www.pluginurl.com/
 * Description: plugin description
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: author name
 * Author URI: http://www.authorurl.com/
 */

function register_wprs(){
    wp_register_style( 'cta_stylesheet', plugins_url( '/css/rs.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cta_stylesheet' );
}

add_action( 'enqueue_scripts', 'register_wprs' );

?>
```

**rs.css**

```
.classname { color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Wordpress (it looks a lot like Wordpress).  The action hook that you want is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `enqueue_scripts`.

Change your last line to

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_wprs' );
```

Comment: yes it is Wordpress and you my good sir are awesome! That worked perfectly!